# SharePoint Online - Display RTF in column

Tags: sharepoint-online, rich-text, column-formatting

I'm trying to display RTF in a column in SharePoint Online. Regardless of what changes I make to the column the RTF formatting is displayed as Plain Text. I have enabled RTF on the column:

[image]

But it still displays as plain text:

[image]

Here is an example of the RTF:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1053{\fonttbl{\f0\fswiss MS Sans Serif;}}
\viewkind4\uc1\pard\f0\fs16 
\par }
```

My question to clarify: Is it possible to paste pre-formatted text as the one above into a RTF enabled column? Or do we have to re-do all the formatting in SharePoint Online?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per my test the RTF formatted text is not supported in SharePoint online Multiple lines of text column.

You need to do all the formatting in SharePoint online default column.